# Disable microsoft word "Show Repairs" dialog box

Tags: vba, documents, repair

In VBA I am cycling through thousands of documents. The script stalls when it hits a document needomg repair. A dialog box opens entitled: "Show Repairs" with the message: "Errors were detected in thsi file, but Word was able to open the file by making the repairs listed below. Save the file to make the repairs permanent".

How do I override the dialog box? I am happy to skip the document altogether. Below is what I tried.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=strMyFile, PasswordDocument:="?#nonsense@$", ReadOnly:=True, OpenAndRepair:=False)
plication.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok the solution is to use Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog instead of Documents.Open. That simple. Apparently.